# How to Query Specific Properties on AEM's Bulk Editor

Tags: aem, gql

While querying using the Bulk Editor, i was able to run queries like

```
"jcr:title":'GeoBlog'  "sling:resourceType":'social/blog/components/page'
```

to search for results with specific title and resource type.

But was not able to run queries for the following
1. cq:template `("cq:template":'/libs/social/blog/templates/page')`
2. cq:LastModifiedBy `("cq:LastModifiedBy":'admin')`
3. jcr:createdBy `("jcr:createdBy":'admin')`
Are there any special syntax in GQL for these properties or any other requirements that i am missing on?
I'm using AEM 6

Comment: I haven't found satisfactory documentation for GQL to query for arbitrary properties.  Instead, I just use it to find everything and dump out any/all properties I am interested in.  From there, you could export into Excel and sort/filter by the properties.  Would that work in your case?

Comment: Bulk Editor is a filter itself. Why would i use an excel filter to filter the end results. I would prefer to have some properties which would give me the filtered result in the first place.

Comment: If you can use BulkEditor as a filter, then by all means do so.  However, you are saying you can't use it that way.  When filtering, I prefer to use QueryBuilder (but that only returns results, not a way to "bulk update" a bunch of the returned values.